# HTML file loaded before doing function in directive file, How to resolve it?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to create an html file only after a function in the directive file finished.
the function get data from REST API function and the html need this data to load itself.
most of times the function really running before the html loaded but very often the page loaded before the function, and then the page is empty with no data.
How to make sure the directive functions always run before the page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i have understood the question correctly - maybe give promises a shot?

1. create a new instance of a deferred object using $q.defer.
2. resolve the response you get from the REST call in using the deferred API.
3. send the request for the new page in the .then() block of the resolved response.

But in honesty, I feel like you're on a wrong path. one would want to separate such concerns. ask yourself why you are send a RESTful request in a directive in the first place. Maybe split out the calling of a service from within a controller.

Some more context on your question would be nice though